# Facebook messages cannot be read on email anymore

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger

I used to read my Facebook messages just from my email, where I usually receive notifications from Facebook.

But, since March 21st, I haven't been able to read the messages that way anymore. I do receive a notification that I've got a message from someone, but I cannot see it from the email.

Any solution?

[image: screen shot of message notification]

Comment: This is my least favourite change that facebook has introduced; I wish they would change it back

Comment: "I do receive a notification that I've got a message from someone"  I don't even get those anymore...

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Facebook has discontinued displaying conversations messages in email notifications and that's kind of disappointing for many users.

**Does Facebook provide an option to revert this?**

Not as of now. We are just stuck with it and for as long as Facebook / Messenger wants us to.

This is a good privacy move because many attackers / hackers find it easier to hack email accounts and servers than a Facebook account so given that a message is sent over email it makes it easier for those who sole aim is to intercept message, which might be private or confidential, so Messenger is strictly keeping it on the app.

On the other hand it is also a good marketing strategy for FB / Messenger to prompt user to use their app more often.

I am pretty sure long ago I created a Facebook app to intercept inbox messages and send it to my email address whenever I got a new message or someone sees my message but I lost my previous account and the app and either do I have the code but looking at the Facebook Graph API it doesn't seem possible now, Facebook has strict regulations on what an app can access. So I am not sure if there exists an app that can help.

Facebook is very "concerned" about privacy, or at least wants to seem like and that might be one reason why they have taken these steps.

Answer (score 1):

Facebook is trying to push people to log on to the sites proper. The same email changes apply to notifications from the main Facebook.com site. They used to show the full content of the post/comment/reply/photo/video, but these days you’re simply given a link to the post in question with no further detail.